# Не могу найти плагинов для построения UML диаграмм по kotlin классам

Tags: kotlin, uml

SimpleUML не работает для kotlin классов, подскажите есть ли какие-то другие плагины для построения UML по kotlin классам

Comment: Тоже искал, но так и не нашёл, помог перевод в Java